# Django debug dictionary's returned from querys

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Is there a way in django to print the dictionary's returned from query sets in the following manner:

```
{
    'key' : value,
    'key' : 'value',
    'keyrecur' : {
       'key' : 'value',
       'key' : value
    }
}
```

Or something in a similar fashion?

Comment: Try looking at the pprint documentation

Comment: Check django serialization https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

Comment: `for key, value in data:`

Comment: @Rohan Just what I was looking for!